# [NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0'

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

i am creating custom cell.

In that i added 3 textfields. so i want to store that textfield values into nsmutablearray.

when i am trying this code

```
UITextField *valueField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165,6, 135, 30)];
valueField.borderStyle =  UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
[cell addSubview:valueField];
[array1 addObject:valueField.text];
[valueField release];
```

i am getting error like this

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0'`

so please tell me the reason 
thanks in advance.

Comment: What is array1 and how is it declared?

Comment: array1 is object of nsmutablearray. and declared as like NSMutableArray *array1;

Comment: Why do you want to add the text of a newly created textfield when you know that there is nothing inside it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UITextField *valueField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165,6, 135, 30)];
valueField.borderStyle =  UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
valueField.text = @"";
[cell addSubview:valueField];
[array1 addObject:valueField.text];
[valueField release];
```

the above code will work fine for you.

Comment: hi rajesh this code is working fine. can please tell me how i can chat with you

Comment: i could not understand what r saying

Comment: can u please tell me. textfield values cannot store in array what is the problem

Comment: @Ram before you store values to array , you need to set the textField text  ,eg: valueField.text = @"hai"; then try add the value to array, you can do it.

Comment: @Ram you can accept this answer helpful by clicking the tick button to green

Answer (score 2):

Just add this condition to check if the textfield is empty (i.e. textfield.text = nil):

```
if (valueField.text != nil) {
     [array1 addObject:valueField.text];
}
else {
     [array1 addObject:@""];
}
```

This will check if textfield is empty it will add an empty string. If you dont want that just skip the else part.

Comment: can u please tell me. textfield values cannot store in array what is the problem

Comment: you should store these values on this delegate callback `textFieldDidEndEditing:`

Comment: when i am insert your code into delegate method it is showing only last field value

Comment: Please study about the delegate callbacks in the documentation and post a new question explaining what you want

Comment: @xs2bush let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2324/discussion-between-ram-and-xs2bush)

Answer (score 2):

The *text* attribute of UITextField is nil by default. Set it to an empty string before adding it to your array, though I think this is not what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you said you declared your array like so:

" declared as like NSMutableArray *array1;"

Have you alloc your array before adding objects to it?

In other words have you done this ?

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

If you only did

```
NSMutableArray *array1;
```

That will only declare a pointer to a NSMutableArray object. It doesn't point to an instance of a NSMutableArray object.

Answer (score 0):

When you put `[array1 addObject:valueField.text];`, you are adding a nil object to your array, just as your error says. How can valueField.text be equal to something when you just initialized and allocated valueField?